# Unregister Windows services during installation (Wix)

Tags: wix, windows-services

An older version of our product installer using something else than Wix 'forgets' to unregister an installed service upon uninstallation.

If we run the current installer (using Wix) it blows up with 'Access denied' when it wants to install the service.

To counter this, I added to the component that installs the service the following:

```
<RemoveRegistryKey Id="ServiceRegistrationRouter" Action="removeOnInstall" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Router" Root="HKLM"/>
```

The 'RemoveRegistryValues' (Sequence 2600) is scheduled well before the 'InstallServices' (Sequence 5800) so that should clean up the lingering registry entries.

That works like a charm, but I still get the 'Access Denied'. So even though the registry entries are gone, Windows still holds on to the service.

I know a 'sc delete' will fix the problem, but if possible, I want to stay clear from a custom action.

Is that possible?

Comment: Do you have a [ServiceControl](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/servicecontrol.html) entry to stop the service in your package on install? I suppose you can remove it too, but stopping might do?

Comment: @Stein: Ouch! I went with the assumption that you can't control what you didn't install. That is not correct obviously. I'll post the code fragment as answer. Thank you for the push in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate `Component` and add it to the desired `ComponentGroup`.
That'll look like this:

```
<Component Id="C_RemoveOldServices" Guid="B7574124-A3A8-4535-A14E-616E5024CA7F" KeyPath="yes">
            <ServiceControl Id="old_service1" Name="Service 1" Remove="install" Wait="no"/>
            <ServiceControl Id="old_service2" Name="Service 2" Remove="install" Wait="no"/>
            <ServiceControl Id="old_service3" Name="Service 3" Remove="install" Wait="no"/>
            <ServiceControl Id="old_service4" Name="Service 4" Remove="install" Wait="no"/>
            <Condition>![CDATA[NOT Installed]]</Condition>
</Component>
```

Comment: Did the Wait="yes" perhaps fail? Just curious.

Comment: Didn't try. I know in my case that the service executable is gone anyway, so there is nothing to wait on. This is why I chose Wait="no".

Comment: OK, so it really was a fragment. Makes sense. Moral of the story is to always use MSI built-in constructs if you can.